# NPM install the latest available version matching with nodejs version

Tags: node.js, npm

On my server I am limited to Nodejs version 11.5 and wanted to install some packages there. Clearly the latest version of the packages does not work on the old Node version. Is there any way to tell npm to install an older version which matches with our Nodejs version? I want a way to automatically find the installable version of package and don't want to use trial and error to find the working package.
Thanks

Comment: No, that isn't available in NPM. Using a non-LTS version of Node is going to make that more challenging too; dropping LTS support is usually a major version change, it's unlikely v11 support was even being tracked.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so we cannot even install the older versions?

Comment: You can install the old versions, but there's nothing in NPM to help you figure out which old versions will work with your version of Node. You can look at package release notes, but again v11 support likely wasn't tracked too closely as it isn't LTS

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks